# is Magento2 Module structure case sensitive?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

First of all, I am using the devbox and I've set the phpstorm as in the docu (remote php and phpunit). Then I have a project in `magento2/app/code/Company` inside I have a framework folder. And all the tests under `Framework` folder are running (also the composer.json and registration.php are set correctly).

Now my question:
when I try to rename the folder from `Company` to `company` and `Framework` to `framework` to look like the magento framework in `magento2/vendor/magento/framework`(all small written) the test don't run anymore. My namespaces are still: "Company\Framework" in composer.json file in all files.

Does that mean that I have to change the whole namespaces? Whereas magento still uses `Magento\Framework` in namespaces. What am I missing and why by Magento that works?

Comment: need to change in all place.

Comment: and then if I have a module named `module-bla-bla` then should that be in namespaces? isn't it something wrong with that?

Comment: yes change all place. because magento find module based on namespace and module name.

Comment: and then how come the /vendor/magento framework works as: small caps for the folders and upper caps for the namespaces?

Comment: @Edwin Magento lets itself do that, 3rd parties can't